# pipenv>2021.11.23 will fail to install package in docker container

Tags: docker, pipenv, python-3.9

Im using ubuntu base image and installing some package on it make our required docker image.

I faced issue that packages are installing which was working fine some days back so I tried whole day to check where is the problem and finally identify that Pipenv not installing package in docker container if we are using version>2021.11.23.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=nonintercative

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y git python3.9 python3-pip python3.9-dev curl python3-dev gcc libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev jq && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime && echo "Asia/Kolkata" > /etc/timezone && mkdir -p /var/run/celery && mkdir -p /var/log/celery/  && mkdir -p /var/www/oms && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

RUN pip install pipenv && pip install -U setuptools && pip install --upgrade awscli

WORKDIR /var/www/oms/

COPY . .

RUN pipenv install --system --deploy
```

**Pipfile**

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
celery="==5.2.3"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have updated changes.

Comment: And how did you verify packages are not being installed? Particularly, why did you use `pipenv install --system`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have verified using pip freeze command. Pipenv to install a Pipfile’s contents into its parent system with the --system flag.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting from a Python base image rather than Ubuntu.

Otherwise, I cannot reproduce the issue and I am using latest pipenv

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y git curl gcc libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev jq \
  && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime && echo "Asia/Kolkata" > /etc/timezone \
  && mkdir -p /var/run/celery \
  && mkdir -p /var/log/celery \
  && mkdir -p /var/www/oms

RUN python -m pip install -U pip

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./
RUN python -m pip install pipenv \
   && pipenv install --system --deploy

# WORKDIR /var/www/oms/
```

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
celery="==5.2.3"
awscli = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

```
$ docker build -t test-pipenv .
$ docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint=pip test-pipenv freeze
...
awscli==1.25.59
celery==5.2.3
pipenv==2022.8.19
```